# Problema com formulário Django:IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

Galera, estou tentando fazer um formulário usando model em Django que salve os dados quando eu clicar no botão e redirecione para uma página, bom consegui fazer a página do formulário, só que depois de colocar os dados necessário e clicar no botão para salvar eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   app_candidato.avaliacao_id

a baixo meus arquivos:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from site_.settings import MEDIA_ROOT

class Criterio(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def  __str__(self):
        return self.label

class Candidato(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    e_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=100, default = '')
    github = models.URLField(default = '')
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=100, default = '')
    cover_letter = models.TextField(default = '')
    Ensino_superior = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    avaliacao = models.ForeignKey(Criterio, default = '')
    med = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    #talvez tenha que alterrar essa linha
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='/home/douglas/Documentos/Django/my-second-blog/site_/media', null=True, blank=True)

    def  __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**urls.py**

```
#from .models import Candidato
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.canditato_list, name='canditato_list'),
    url(r'^candidato/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.candidato_detalhe, name='candidato_detalhe'),
    url(r'^cadastrar/$', views.cadastrar, name='cadastrar'),    
    url(r'^candidato/[0-9]+/avaliacao/$', views.avaliar, name='avaliar'), 

]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Candidato, Criterio
from django import forms
from .forms import CandForm, AvalForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
def canditato_list(request):
    candidatos = Candidato.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'app/candidato_list.html', {'candidatos': candidatos})
def candidato_detalhe(request, pk):
    candidato = get_object_or_404(Candidato, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'app/candidato_detalhe.html', {'candidato': candidato})
def avaliar(request):
    criterios = Criterio.objects.all()
    form2 = AvalForm()
    return render(request, 'app/avaliacao.html', {'criterios': criterios})
def cadastrar(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CandForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('candidato_detalhe', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CandForm()
    return render(request, 'app/cadastro.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import Candidato, Criterio
from django import forms

class CandForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Candidato
        fields = ('name', 'e_mail', 'github', 'linkedin', 'Ensino_superior')

class AvalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Criterio
        fields = ('label',)
```

**template(cadastro.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cadastro</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Cadastro</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Guardar</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Como o campo avaliação do modelo Candidato é uma ForeignKey tenta deixar o valor default como 1 ou algum valor já existente, para isso já deve haver um Critério cadastrado.

Comment: avaliacao = models.ForeignKey(Criterio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)... sem especificar o on_delete ao apagar o registro da tabela não sera deletada o conjunto da relação que esta vinculada. so por o mouse sobre tera um mensagem "Parameter 'on_delete' unfilled". paramentro nao preenchido.

Comment: faz essa pequena alteração se nada resultar informe :)

Answer (score 0):

Como o atributo `avaliacao` é uma ForeignKey e não é obrigatório, você pode defini-lo como nulo.

```
avaliacao = models.ForeignKey(Criterio, null=True, blank=True)
```

Mais detalhes na [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#null)